# Why can we push function object to std::thread directly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, std

I'm a little bit confuse about why we can do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::thread> vec;
vec.reserve(2);
vec.emplace_back(std::bind(silly, 1));
vec.emplace_back(std::bind(silly, 2));

for (auto i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    vec[i].join();
}
// for folks who see this post after
// you can use push_back() like this:
vec.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(silly, 3)));
```

The code above, we push function object to thread vector directly, and I don't know why it is acceptable. Because from my knowledge thread vector could only push thread type object to it. Just like for a int vector, we could only push int type object to it.

The example below is what I can 100% understand, because we push thread object into thread vector!

```
std::vector<std::thread> vecOfThreads;
std::function<void()> func = []() {
    //Do Some Important Work
    // .....
    //Print Thread ID
    std::cout << "From Thread ID : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
};
vecOfThreads.push_back(std::thread(func));
std::thread th1(func);
vecOfThreads.push_back(std::move(th1));
for (std::thread &th: vecOfThreads) {
    // If thread Object is Joinable then Join that thread.
    if (th.joinable())
        th.join();
}
```

Any explanation and suggested material for studying this part is appreciated!

Comment: You don't push, you *emplace*. Which creates the objects in-place by forwarding the `emplace_back` arguments to the `std::thread` constructor. It's somewhat similar to *placement new*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, oops I kind of forgot that. Yeah because it is emplace_back! emplace_back() will call the constructor explicitly. So actually what happened about vec.emplace_back(std::bind(silly, 1)), is calling vec.emplace_back(std::thread(std::bind(silly, 1))); right? 

Comment: @Peter No, emplace_back() is a specialised function that receives the constructor's parameters as an argument. So it really is calling `vec.emplace_back(std::bind(silly, 1))`. **However**, the `std::thread(std::function &)` constructor is used internally, within `emplace_back`.

Comment: It seems like I have wrong understanding before. Thanks for your further explanation @Alceste_ 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** *I missread code sample, as stated in comments, in this particular case of `emplace_back`, the constructor is called without going through the implicit conversion chain, as is the purpose of emplace_back. Leaving the rest nonetheless since question was about pushing.*

C++ offers [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), which is what enables you to do thing like :

```
double a = 0;
```

Without getting an error due to assigning an int literal (0) to a double-type variable (a).

The above link can give you detailed explanation on implicit conversion, but that part that interest us is that :

> A user-defined conversion consists of zero or one non-explicit single-argument [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) or non-explicit conversion function call

In `std::thread` [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), there is a constructor that takes a std::function (and optionally its arguments), so it could be used to automagically convert functions into threads when pushing to thread vector, if the rest of the chain is respected *(which apparently it isn't)*. In your code sample, it is directly called without implicit conversions limitations.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do realize that is a magic of emplace_back! I found that if I replace emplace_back with push_back, then that line would show error! If I want to use push_back() at here, I have to push_back(std::thread(std::bind(silly, 2)))